# int objective not iterable error

Tags: python, int, typeerror

I'm a new one in coding with python, but I had to finish one project work for my school related to Crude Oil scheduling problem.  When I run the code I got an error message

> int objective not iterable error.

My code:

```
enter code here 
#Here my code:
#indeces:
T = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
M = [1,2,3,4]  
#Continuous Variables:
for m in M:
    for c in C:
        for t in T:
            VCT[m,c,t] = model.addVar(obj = 0.0, vtype = 'C', name = 'VCT[%s,%s,%s]'%(m,c,t))
for m in M:
    for t in T:
        V[m,t] = model.addVar(obj = 0.0, vtype = 'C' , name = 'V[%s,%s]'%(m,t))
#Constraints:
for m in M:
    for t in T:
        model.addConstr(V[m,t], '=', quicksum(VCT[m,c,t] for c in C)) #28 
        model.addConstr(V[m,t], '<=',V_U[m]) #29
        model.addConstr(V[m,t], '>=',V_L[m]) #30
```

Comment: there's no c list in the program , can you change this and add the full program please

Comment: And provide the traceback too

Comment: ' C = ['SAL','OMN']

Comment: Where does the error happen and what are `VCT`, `V_U`, `V_L` and `V`?

Comment: How can I provide traceback? I tried with print tb(), but it doesn't work.

Comment: The error comes from:  for m in M:

Comment: I can post my whole code ich you want

Comment: V_U = {1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0} 
V_L = {1:1000,2:1000,3:1000,4:1000} they are upper and lower capacity     VCT = {} # continuous variable Amount of crude c in tank m at the end of period t
V = {} # continuous variable Crude level in tank m at the end of period t

Comment: Please do. And post the error too

Answer (score -2):

Ofcourse, that error makes sense....

**There is no "C" array** 
`for c in C:` How will this work... ? I dunno what "C" means!!

 So create a array named "C" or remove that if you dont need that.... A elaboration of your code will help..

Comment: But I am summing c... quicksum(..... for c in C). Anyway I added c (for c in C) in my code, but I get the same error.